# Cleanthesis TeX Theme wont create pdf

Tags: pdf, latex, pdflatex, tex-live

Im trying to build a (the thesis-example.tex) PDF with the cleanthesis theme (http://cleanthesis.der-ric.de/) and it wont work

The last failure is:

```
! pdfTeX error (font expansion): auto expansion is only possible with scalable 
fonts.
\AtBegShi@Output ...ipout \box \AtBeginShipoutBox 
                                                  \fi \fi 
l.107 \cleardoublepage

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on thesis-example.log.
```

Im currently on a Fed26 System with ***5928*** installed texlive packages.
(dnf install texlive-scheme-full, dnf install texlive-*)

If i try this with a complete stock Ubuntu 16.04 and texlive-publisher and texlive-full packages it works. So i guess there is no missing package.

I you need specific parts of thesis-example.log, let me know i cant paste it because its too large

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i installed a clean Fed26 and loaded all texlive packages i had on the main pc. I compared `/etc/texlive/web2c/updmap.cfg` and i saw that my `updmap.cfg` was currupted.

I copied the working `updmap.cfg` to my main system and did a "`updmap-sys --force`" and now it works